# How to use same header and navigation menus across the whole website with different subfolders in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I have this code:

```
<header id="mainHeader">
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="callus">
        <p>
            <img src="images/callus.jpg" alt="" class="fl" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li class="links"><a href="default.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li class="links"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="links"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="links"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li class="links"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I have put it in a user control called header.ascx and declared it in a web.config file. Its working fine when i am calling it from any page which is on the same directory level. But once i call it from a subfolder the logo image disappears and links doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the image src from your sites home directory. If your images folder is in your sites home directory, then you need a slash in front of it..

```
<img src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: I am using this code in a user control. Preceding the path with '/' isn't working.